# Why am I getting a nil when I click a second time?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer

I have a table view populated with song titles and artist. I have a server up and I retrieve songs from there. It works perfectly fine when I click the first time, but when I click another cell I get the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell: VenueCell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! VenueCell

    cell.songtitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.songartist.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    controltitle.text = songtitles[indexPath.row]
    controlartist.text = songartists[indexPath.row]


    let spacesongs = songtitles[indexPath.row].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

    if let url: String = "hiding link"{

        let urlplayer = NSURL(string: url)
        let playeritem = AVPlayerItem(URL:(urlplayer)!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playeritem)
        print(url)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerDidFinishPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playeritem)
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector:Selector("setProgress"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        print(counter)
        print("current \(CMTimeGetSeconds(playeritem.currentTime()))")
        self.player.volume = 1.0
        self.player.rate = 1.0
        self.player.play()

        playpause.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause"), forState: .Normal)

    }
```

Comment: debug in xcode and see on which line that error occurs.

Comment: It does not give me a certain line. This is what I get http://puu.sh/nTXkj/0e717b2fb4.png

Comment: click around in the left panel and you'll see

Comment: http://puu.sh/nTXs6/7e20922a8b.png

Comment: Click on 1. From looking at this you can already tell that the problem is in `didDeselectRowatIndexPath:`

Comment: Yup that was the problem thanks.